# React Bootstrap: Vertical alignment of row's columns?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap, I am trying to align items vertically within a row but with no luck. My problem is I have a button in one of the columns, so for the other columns all the texts are shifted up a bit while the button and its content have a larger height. 
My question is how can I make all columns within a row to have the same height and to all align in the middle vertically? 
The only solution I managed to find so far is using CSS:
    tranform: translateY(-50%)
this does the trick, but I was looking for a better more dynamic solution as this needs to be applied for every column excepts for the button column

EDIT: When I say columns and rows, I'm talkign about bootstrap's Col and Row, not actually a table or rows and columns; sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using table rows, you can wrap contents within a `<div>..</div>`

like:

```
<tr>
  <div classname="align-me"></div>
</tr>
```

and then you can use flexbox to align them dynamically:

```
tr .align-me {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was actually referring to bootstrap's 'col' and 'row' classes, and not to the actual HTML tables

Comment: can you post the related code snippet or a jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 33):

You can apply any of Bootstrap's classes to a React Bootstrap component. So, per [the Grid System docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/), the following columns will both be centered vertically:

```
<Row className="align-items-center">
  <Col>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{details}</p>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <button>{callToAction}</button>
  </Col>
</Row>;
```

Comment: At least this answer works for me. I suggest react-bootstrap team update the docs ASAP. Sometimes I am not quite sure if all the features from Bootstrap are also valid in reactjs bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I found this:

```
<td className="align-middle"></td>
```

ref: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/bootstrap+table+text+vertical+align+center

Answer (score 0):

I tried the snippet in @kburgie's answer, but it did not work for me, my `Row` wouldn't budge an inch. So, I drew a border around that `Row`, to figure out what was happening.

Seems that `Row` has just enough `height` to fit its children, not an inch more, and that's why it can't move vertically. Gave the row some `height`, and it worked effortlessly.

```
.viewport-height {
     height: 100vh;
}

<Row className="align-items-center viewport-height">
  <Col>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{details}</p>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <button>{callToAction}</button>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Could've added this as a comment to @kburgie, but I lack reputation.