# react-bootstrap align-middle not working for Columns

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap

According to bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/) I should be able to vertically align something inside of a column by using the `align-middle` class. I have written this code in typescript, react-bootstrap and `align-middle` is not working for me.

```
    const Style = styled.div<StyledProps>`
      .fixed {
        background-image: url(${props => props.image? props.image : '../img/matrix.jpg'});
        background-repeat: none;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 400px;
      }
    `;
    
    export const FixedBackground = () => {return (
      <Style image={matrix}>
        <Container>
          <Row className="text-light py-5 align-items-center align-middle align-items-center">
            <Col className="col col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center fixed align-middle align-items-center">
              <h1 className="align-middle">Advance to the next level</h1>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Style>
    )};
```

I want the `h1` tag to be in the vertical center of the image... but it appears on the top.  I also googled and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484040/react-bootstrap-vertical-alignment-of-rows-columns) but the suggestion of adding `align-items-center` doesn't work for me.

Comment: is you column display flex? if not add d-flex class with your column

Comment: yes that works. I also see that `text-center` class on the `Col` doesn't horizontally center after adding d-flex. Can I get both horizontal and vertical center?

Comment: Also, can you respond as answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `d-flex` with your `Col` to make it `display:flex`.
You can use class `justify-content-centre` to center your content horizontally.
Use class `align-items-center` to center your content vertically.